# Batch Script FOR loop to change file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a file that looks like this:

```
Disk:Bus 0 Enclosure 7 Disk 14.
State:Enabled
Raw Capacity:402.61GB
User Capacity:214.29GB
LUN ID:18
LUN Type:RAID 5
Hot Spare Replacing:N/A
Firmware:C3A8
Vendor:HITACHI 
Model:HUS15604 CLAR450
Bind Signature:0xcdc0
CLARiiON TLA Part Number:005049032
Drive Type:FC
Current Speed:4Gbps
Maximum Speed:4Gbps


Disk:Bus 0 Enclosure 7 Disk 13.
State:Enabled
Raw Capacity:402.61GB
User Capacity:214.29GB
LUN ID:18
LUN Type:RAID 5
Hot Spare Replacing:N/A
Firmware:C3A8
Vendor:HITACHI 
Model:HUS15604 CLAR450
Bind Signature:0xcdc0
CLARiiON TLA Part Number:005049032
Drive Type:FC
Current Speed:4Gbps
Maximum Speed:4Gbps


Disk:Bus 0 Enclosure 7 Disk 12.
State:Enabled
Raw Capacity:402.61GB
User Capacity:214.29GB
LUN ID:18
LUN Type:RAID 5
Hot Spare Replacing:N/A
Firmware:C3A8
Vendor:HITACHI 
Model:HUS15604 CLAR450
Bind Signature:0xcdc0
CLARiiON TLA Part Number:005049032
Drive Type:FC
Current Speed:4Gbps
Maximum Speed:4Gbps
```

I would like to read the file and write to look like this:

```
Disk            State     Raw_Capacity  User_Capacity
Bus 0 Enclosure 7 Disk 14.  Enabled 402.61GB              214.29GB
Bus 0 Enclosure 7 Disk 13.  Enabled 402.61GB              214.29GB
Bus 0 Enclosure 7 Disk 12.  Enabled 402.61GB              214.29GB
```

Trying to use FOR loop. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Show us what you have tried till now.. This is not google..

Comment: What operating system are you using? What do you mean by "batch-file"? Windows CMD.EXE? Why do you have to use that? Can you not use PowerShell?

Answer (score 1):

you might try this:

```
@echo off &setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in (file) do (
    set "line=%%a"
    if /i "!line:Disk:=!" neq "!line!" <nul set/p"=!line:*Disk:=!   "
    if /i "!line:Raw=!" neq "!line!" <nul set/p"=!line:*Capacity:=! "
    if /i "!line:User=!" neq "!line!" <nul set/p"=!line:*Capacity:=!"
    if /i "!line:Maximum Speed=!" neq "!line!" echo(
)
```

---

output is:

```
Bus 0 Enclosure 7 Disk 14.      402.61GB        214.29GB
Bus 0 Enclosure 7 Disk 13.      402.61GB        214.29GB
Bus 0 Enclosure 7 Disk 12.      402.61GB        214.29GB
```

Answer (score 1):

`file.log` is the input file here.  I've used Endoro's techniques but with some small changes.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
(
echo Disk            State     Raw_Capacity  User_Capacity
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("file.log") do (
    set "line=%%a"
    if /i "!line:Disk:=!" neq "!line!" <nul set/p"=!line:*Disk:=!   "
    if /i "!line:State=!" neq "!line!" <nul set/p"=!line:*State:=!   "
    if /i "!line:Raw=!"   neq "!line!" <nul set/p"=!line:*Capacity:=! "
    if /i "!line:User=!"  neq "!line!" <nul set/p"=!line:*Capacity:=!"&echo(
)
)>"output file.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another variation on the theme :)

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
>output.txt (
  echo Disk            State     Raw_Capacity  User_Capacity
  for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in (input.txt) do (
    for %%V in (Disk State "Raw Capacity") do if %%~V==%%A set "%%A=%%B"
    if "%%A"=="User Capacity" echo !Disk!  !State! !Raw Capacity!              %%B
  )
)
```